# Removing all child node elements from XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have the following XML structure:

## XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Users>
</Users>
```

At some point, the `<Users>` gets filled up with different users, but I want to be able to delete them all in a single, simple function.

## Attempt

```
/// <summary>
/// Removes all nodes from XML creds file on application close
/// </summary>
public static void RemoveXMLData()
{
    string xmlPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\Credential.xml");
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
    document.RemoveNodes();
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I've done the following as well:

## Attempt #2

```
        string xmlPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\Credential.xml");
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

        foreach (var node in document.Descendants("Users"))
        {
            node.Remove();
        }
```

But this yields an exception error.

At the end of the day, I just want to get back to square one with the following file data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Users>
</Users>
```

Comment: Just bake a fresh one? `new XDocument(new XElement("Users"));`

Comment: Did you try searching before posting the question? Check [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298018/how-to-remove-all-the-childnodes-of-the-specified-xmlnode-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Comment: Is `Users` the only node in the XML? If it is why don't you just write over the file with a new XDocument with an empty user node?

Comment: Did you expect calling `RemoveNodes()` to save the file back to disk? It's unclear what you mean by "doesn't seem to be working".

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, good point. This fixed it by calling save method. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
document.Descendants("Users").Elements().Remove();
```

As suggested by @Cory, Alternative and faster approach would be:

```
document.Root.Elements().Remove();
```

Comment: Calling .Save() on that fixed my issue, thanks.

Comment: `document.Root.Elements().Remove()` would be faster, prevent scanning the entire tree. `Descendants()` is rarely a method you want to use.

Comment: Agreed! Updated the answer based on you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It probably blows up on the second attempt as you are iterating the collection you remove from.  Try this.

```
    string xmlPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\Credential.xml");
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);

    var nodes = document.Descendants("Users");
    while(nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        nodes[0].Remove();
    }
```